# AJAX long polling not working with IE

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, long-polling

I seem to be having a problem with long polling and IE.  This is my first foray into long polling, so I set up a simple test to see if I could make it work.  It seems to behave just fine with FF and Chrome, but I'm getting different results with IE.

First, here's some code:

**HTML/Javascript:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function()
{
    (function poll()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'events/alert-data.php',
            success: function (e)
            {
                $('#results').append($('<div>Success: ' + e.text + '</div>').fadeIn(1000));
            },
            error: function (e)
            {
                console.log(e);
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: poll,
            timeout: 10000
        });
    })();
});
//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="results">hello</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$time = time();

while (time() - $time < 5) { }

echo json_encode(array('text' => time()));

?>
```

In FF/Chrome, I'm seeing expected data:

```
hello
Success: 1356104196
Success: 1356104201
Success: 1356104217
Success: 1356104222
Success: 1356104227
```

But in IE it repeats the first `Success` line infinitely.  At least I presume it's infinite as it locks up the browser and won't allow me to scroll.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldn't there be some sort of `setTimeout` delay? the code would just infinity call `poll` without ever pausing in between calls. even if your php is waiting 5 seconds before responding, ajax is asyncronous and the browser will continue to make requests as fast as it can while php waits.

Comment: @jbabey - No, I don't think so because `$.ajax` is deferred in jQuery, so it won't call `poll` until the call completes.  At least I think that's correct.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The delay is induced server-side.

Comment: The problem with IE would appear to be the consequence of caching,  probably by IE itself. This could potentially happen in any browser. Try adding `cache: false` to the ajax options.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot - Brilliant!  That seemed to fix it.  Make it an answer and I'll vote it as correct.  Thanks! :)

Comment: OK, SenorAmor (Mr Love), will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with IE would appear to be the consequence of caching, probably by IE itself. This could potentially happen in any browser.

Try adding :

```
cache: false
```

to the ajax options.

Comment: Wow, that's the quickest acceptance ever. I barely got my finger off the mouse button!

Comment: That's just how I roll, baby.

Comment: :), And the internet must be in overdrive.