# Long polling a node.js server url not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, internet-explorer, long-polling

So i am trying to test this application that uses long polling with jquery to query a server written with node.js. The long polling code is

```
(function poll(){
        $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost:3000/test", 
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
        }, dataType: "html", complete: poll, timeout: 100000});
    })();
```

the server-side code is actually fairly simple, as it can be seen below.

```
var http = require('http').Server(app);
app.get('/test', function(req, res){
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
 setTimeout(function(){
    res.send(JSON.stringify({"msg":"stuff"}));
},10000);

});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

So the idea is simple i have written a client-side js library that uses jquery to long-poll a server and shows some data when the server sends it some. The server could be written in anything really? I have used node.js to get something going quickly enough for testing. This works well in both Firefox and Chrome but it does not work in IE.

FYI, I have changed the code and removed all the code that is specific to my application, as it is really not necessary to post some really long code.

To be specific, i am using IE10.

I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13993056/ajax-long-polling-not-working-with-ie) and setting the cache to false does not seem to work for me. I cannot even get the first request going.

Answer (score -1):

For IE you may want to change your code to set a timeout to call itself rather than relying on the timeout/completion in your ajax call. That may sort it.

Plus, add a simple unique value onto the URI for each call. So try something like this instead:

```
(function poll() {
    $.ajax({ url: "http://localhost:3000/test?date=" + Date.now(), 
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }, dataType: "html"
    });
    setTimeout(poll, 100000);    
})();
```

Comment: but would that defeat the purpose of long polling? http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery

Comment: No, its the same way of succeeding at the same thing, only one is supported by more browsers.

Comment: the whole purpose of long-polling is to keep an open connection so the server only sends the data when it has some. I am not fully convinced that IE cannot do long-polling so i am not going to resort to polling. If you have any link or document that presents evidence that IE cannot do long-polling feel free to pass it on and i will change my solution.

Answer (score -1):

Probably a bug in jQuery's AJAX.  add some console.log() statements to both server and client and see if IE sends the same data as the popular browsers.